# How to create a Runnable Jar File on Mac with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, zip, executable-jar

I am currently trying to turn my Java project into a Jar file but I have run  into a problem. When exporting the project, I am forced to add a .zip extension to my file to export it. When I unzip the file, I am left with a fileName.jar file but it is a folder. Shouldn't it be a file that I can double click and open? Or is that only on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using 'File > Export > Runnable JAR file'.

In the export destination 'Browse' dialog just enter the jar file name with **no** extension. You should see that the Export destination field then has the '.jar' appended. The export should then create a jar file as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I removed the .zip extension and now it is allowing me to export properly.